# Controller Mods For Skyrim on the Xbox 360

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I was wondering if there was any way to modify the control scheme a bit more for skyrim on the Xbox360. I've been looking around, and though I know mods like [this](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/49471/?) aren't readily available to us console users, I was wondering if there were something similar? If there is any info, kindly share. Thanks  :)

Comment: You can, its just illegal

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to mod Skyrim on the console platforms with out breaking the ToS and EULA of both the 360 and Skyrim.